# Why is my Spring Boot Application exiting after starting when ran with 'java -jar'

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar, executable-jar

I have a simple spring boot application with the following in my build.gradle...

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

When I run `gradle bootRun` everything works great but when I run `gradle assemble` and then try running the jar with `java -jar` the application seems to boot properly and I see

```
13:21:41.132 [main] INFO com.jrgleason.App -- Started App in 1.104 seconds (process running for 1.312
```

But it immediately stops running after that. How do I tell the `java -jar` command to keep running?

Comment: "*How do I tell the java -jar command to keep running?*" - You don't. The application should keep running. This is an indication for another issue. Can you [edit] the post and add the relevant code?

Comment: Remove the  `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, it's conflicting with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: I tried that but the same issue I actually just added it back after I saw a couple posts and wanted to include it in case someone suggested it.